# Ребята, на помощь, как подключить рандом к этой фигне, я сделал чтобы оно выдавало 4 записи, а хочется чтобы выдавало 1 рандомом из 50

Tags: python

```
@dp.message_handler(Text(equals="TEXT"))
async def get_last_five_newsy(message: types.Message):
    with open(os.path.abspath("newr_dict.json")) as file:
        newr_dict = json.load(file)

    for k, v, in sorted(newr_dict.items())[:4]:
        news = f"{v['movieItem_title']}\n" \
               f"{v['movieItem_details']}\n" \
               f"{v['movieItem_url']}"
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: заголовок вопроса переделайте так, чтобы он не был похож на пост с анимешного форума. Сам вопрос должен быть в теле вопроса в развернутом виде.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Поскольку воспроизводимого примера не видать ограничусь общим примером

```py
from random import choices, choice

d = {
    'a': 1,
    'b': 2,
    'c': 3,
    'd': 4
}
# Выбираем случайное одно из случайных 2х
print(
    choice(choices([*d.items()], k=2))
)
```